# How to save Text of several QtextEdits within python PYQt4?

Tags: save, qtextedit

Could you please help me in solving this issue as i am a python PyQt beginner ...i have created a simple application with python PyQt4 for a simple math calculations and having the result in textEdit2 and textEdit3 every thing went fine when i click on calculate push button, values appear in the above textedits...what i want is to save the results on the same text edits so that next time when i open the application and open the data file i find every thing in place. I created the save and open actions...but it saves all the results in the same text edit..

i am attaching my code and also the main window with results that needed to be saved and another shot after saving and opening the application and having all the results in one textedit

```
enter code here
import sys  
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic   
import os   #os used to interface with windows  
import datetime as dt
import pickle
qtCreatorFile = "save.ui" # Enter ui file here

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)   

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):  
    def __init__(self):                         

        super (MyApp,self).__init__()       
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()
        self.calc.clicked.connect(self.Bss)

    def Bss (self):
        x = float(self.textEdit.toPlainText())     
        y = float(self.textEdit1.toPlainText())
        z= x+y
        w= x**2

        z_string = str(z)         #convert z value to a string then add this  string to textEdit and set as Text
        self.textEdit2.setText(z_string)
        w_string = str(w)
        self.textEdit3.setText(w_string)

    def initUI(self):           #QAction class insert New,action save in the main menue bar
        newAction = QtGui.QAction('New', self)  
        newAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newAction.setStatusTip('Create new file')
        newAction.triggered.connect(self.newFile)  
        saveAction = QtGui.QAction('Save as', self)
        saveAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        saveAction.setStatusTip('Save current file')
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)
        openAction = QtGui.QAction('Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        closeAction = QtGui.QAction('Close', self)
        closeAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        closeAction.setStatusTip('Close Notepad')
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
        self.show()
        self.statusBar()

    def newFile(self): #create a new function and remove all values in the QTEXTedit
        self.textEdit.clear()
        self.textEdit1.clear()
        self.textEdit2.clear()
        self.textEdit3.clear()                

    def openFile(self):
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        filedata = f.read()
        self.textEdit1.setText(filedata)
        self.textEdit2.setText(filedata)
        self.textEdit3.setText(filedata)
        f.close()
        self.show()

    def saveFile(self):   # saving argument values in a filedata
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', os.getenv('HOME'))
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        filedata = self.textEdit1.toPlainText()
        f.write(filedata)
        filedata = self.textEdit2.toPlainText()
        f.write(filedata)
        filedata = self.textEdit3.toPlainText()
        f.write(filedata)
        f.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
        QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question properly, since you are writing textEdit values to a file in order, you'll need to read that values line by line when opening the file, instead of reading the whole file content using *read()* method. so the openFile() method should be something like this:

```
def openFile(self):
    self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))
    count = 0
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            count = count + 1
            if count == 1 : self.textEdit1.setText(line)
            elif count == 2 : self.textEdit2.setText(line)
            elif count == 3 : self.textEdit3.setText(line)
            else: break
    self.show()
```

hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

also change saveFile() method like below:

```
def saveFile(self):   # saving argument values in a filedata
    self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', os.getenv('HOME'))
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    filedata = self.textEdit1.toPlainText()
    filedata = str(filedata)+"\n"
    f.write(filedata)
    filedata = self.textEdit2.toPlainText()
    filedata = str(filedata)+"\n"
    f.write(filedata)
    filedata = self.textEdit3.toPlainText()
    filedata = str(filedata)+"\n"
    f.write(filedata)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Soheil for your reply; i am looking for saving each value in its own textEdit and in order. Trying your solution ..when i open the file...will create all the values in one textEdit only ...leaving the others with empty values...any ideas about how i can apply that?

Comment: guess in saveFile() method, you are writing all data in a single line. if that is the case, append the '\n' character to each filedata variable in saveFile() method and that will do it